# SDL_CreateRenderer cannot find a matching driver to create a renderer

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

Here is a simple code to control the movement a rectangle on the screen.
The platform is Windows 10 and mingw32 is used to compile the code.

The follwing cmake script is used to build the code.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(main C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main mingw32 SDL2main SDL2)
```

When ran the following output is generated.

```
Error in create_renderer Couldn't find matching render driver
Process finished with exit code 1
```

And the code is as follows.

```
// #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

void init() {
    int error = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    if (error){
        printf("Error in init: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);

    }
}

SDL_Window* create_window(SDL_Point size, const char* title) {
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, size.x, size.y, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Error in create_window %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }
    return window;
}

SDL_Renderer* create_renderer(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Point size) {

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1,  SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE | SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    if (renderer == NULL) {
        printf("Error in create_renderer %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(renderer, size.x, size.y);
    return renderer;
}

void clean_up(SDL_Renderer *renderer, SDL_Window *window) {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    init();

    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Point window_size = {1280, 720};
    window = create_window(window_size, "Window");

    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    renderer = create_renderer(window, window_size);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);

    SDL_Rect player = {100, 100, 20, 20};

    int should_exit = 0;
    while (!should_exit) {
        SDL_Event event;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                should_exit = 1;
                clean_up(renderer, window);
            }
            else if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                        player.x++;
                        break;

                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                        player.x--;
                        break;

                    case SDLK_DOWN:
                        player.y++;
                        break;

                    case SDLK_UP:
                        player.y--;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &player);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I searched for duplicate questions and their solution was to update the graphics driver and check that the corresponding subsystems are initialized before calling SDL_CreateRenderer.

I have the latest nvidia drivers installed to no avail, and as you can see the initialization order is correct. Can you guide me as to find the reason why?

Comment: What if you pass `0` instead of `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE | SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED`? Maybe those flags conflict with each other?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I tried passing `0` as flag to both `SDL_CreateWindow` and `SDL_CreateRenderer` functions and each one separately but the issue persists.

Comment: Also `create_window` and `create_renderer` have to take window/renderer pointers by reference...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Can you elaborate?, because to my understanding  `SDL_CreateWindow` and `SDL_CreateRenderer`  allocate the memory internally and return a pointer to the allocated memory.

Comment: Yes, but still `window = SDL_CreateWindow` doesn't change the `window` variable in `main`, only it's copy in `create_window`, and same for the renderer. Change the function parameters to `SDL_Window *&window` and `SDL_Renderer *&renderer`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I tried your point but now it's complaining about syntax error. I also tried returning the outputs of `SDL_CreateWindow` and `SDL_CreateRenderer` functions explicitly as the output of `create_window` and `create_renderer` functions respectively, but it didn't help. anyway thanks for your time

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice this is C rather than C++. Then you'd need double pointers instead of references... Can you post the new version of the code where you return the pointers?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry I had to post the code to pastebin otherwise it post would be too long. here is the link [link](https://pastebin.com/FvF0Vgc5)
But I don't think the problem is with the pointers, because I moved everything in main and still the issue exists. I think the problem is with SDL, maybe a bug, or my setup

Comment: Pastebin link works for me, but only if SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE is omitted (i.e. `flags` is *only* `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED`). Otherwise I get the same error. Seems like everything is as it should be, as renderer that is both software and accelerated makes no sense.

Comment: @keltar I tried your points to to avail, I guess it is in fact a system issue if not a bug. thanks for your time.